# d3.geo.tile - Tiles don't render when zoom >=14 in IE/Edge

Tags: internet-explorer, d3.js, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge, d3.geo

I can't work out the reason for this as it seems to work fine in other browsers, but when zooming in to zoom level 14 or higher I get a white page in Internet Explorer 11 and Edge.

When I look at the DOM Inspector its as though the tiles are rendering in the wrong place (somewhere outside the window). This is true even for the demos e.g. http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4132797. I'm trying to render vector tiles (something like this http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5593150) but get the same problem. At other zoom levels it works well, so it must be something to do with how it calculates the position of the tiles?

Any help/ideas would be great. I also posted an issue on github as it seems like it may be a bug, but it doesn't seem very active there.

Thanks

Comment: I see [the issue](http://i.stack.imgur.com/wxt5f.gif) you're reporting, and I have filed a bug for the Microsoft Edge team to investigate the matter further. Thank you for sharing your find with us.

Comment: Great, thanks for looking into it